# What are good ways to publicise security.stackexchange at conferences and events

Tags: discussion

As an extension to [this question](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/57/485), we plan to publicise this forum at the B-Sides in San Francisco and London, so are thinking up useful marketing ideas - but thought it would be useful to get the community's thoughts. These will also be useful at other events where relevant.

Currently we have thought of blogging before, during and after the event, branded swag, networking outside relevant talks, schmoozing useful speakers, sponsoring speakers etc.

Please post any ideas below

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you got it mostly covered....

One other thing I'd suggest, get the updated list of talks, and find/ask relevant questions here (ahead of time). Then, you can publicizse links to that question(s) in the context of the talk...
E.g. if there is a twitter feed or hashtag for the conf, throw up links there during the talk, preferably linking/mentioning the talk it is relevant to...

This can also show the benefit of the site - relevant information on any security topic - and not just publicity...

Comment: cheers. The realtime twitter comment / links to questions is a good one

Comment: This is a great idea.  Getting people to take a glance at the site is one thing, but showing them specific value and relevance is going to encourage them to stick around.