# What questions are relevant to 2011 Black Hat Briefings?

Tags: discussion, conference, site-promotion

In response to [Promoting IT Security at the Black Hat Conference](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339)

Please list a question that is relevent for one or more Black Hat Briefings.
Descriptions for each talk can be found at [Black Hat ® Technical Security Conference: USA 2011](https://www.blackhat.com/html/bh-us-11/bh-us-11-briefings.html)

- Faces Of Facebook-Or, How The Largest Real ID Database In The World Came To Be
- Security When Nano-seconds Count
- War Texting: Identifying and Interacting with Devices on the Telephone Network
- Automated Detection of HPP Vulnerabilities in Web Applications
- Exploiting Siemens Simatic S7 PLCs
- Femtocells: A poisonous needle in the operator's hay stack
- **Post Memory Corruption Memory Analysis**
- Pulp Google Hacking:The Next Generation Search Engine Hacking Arsenal
- Beyond files undeleting: OWADE
- Physical Memory Forensics for Cache
- Lives On The Line: Defending Crisis Maps in Libya, Sudan, and Pakistan
- Legal Aspects of Cybersecurity–(AKA) CYBERLAW: A Year in Review, Cases, issues,  your questions my (alleged) answers
- **Apple iOS Security Evaluation: Vulnerability Analysis and Data Encryption**
- **Mobile Malware Madness, and How To Cap the Mad Hatters**
- USB: Undermining Security Barriers
- Bit-squatting: DNS Hijacking without exploitation
- Virtualization Under Attack: Breaking out of KVM
- Exploiting the iOS Kernel
- Spy-Sense: Spyware Tool for Executing Stealthy Exploits Against Sensor Networks
- Tamper Evident Seals: Design and Security
- The Law of Mobile Privacy and Security
- PANEL: Trillions of Lines of Code and Counting: Securing Applications At Scale
- Smartfuzzing The Web: Carpe Vestra Foramina
- **Hacking Androids for Profit**
- Hacking Google Chrome OS
- Don't Drop the SOAP: Real World Web Service Testing for Web Hackers
- Black Ops of TCP/IP 2011
- Chip & PIN is definitely broken
- ARM exploitation ROPmap
- Don't Hate the Player, Hate the Game: Inside the Android Security Patch Lifecycle
- Hacking and Forensicating an Oracle Database Server
- Windows Hooks of Death: Kernel Attacks Through User-Mode Callbacks
- SSL And The Future Of Authenticity
- Hacking .Net Applications: The Black Arts
- Covert Post-Exploitation Forensics With Metasploit
- Vulnerabilities of Wireless Water Meter Networks
- Battery Firmware Hacking
- From Redmond with Love!
- Owning the Routing Table: New OSPF Attacks
- Reviving Smart Card Analysis
- Sophail: A Critical Analysis of Sophos Antivirus
- Exploiting USB Devices with Arduino
- Microsoft Vista: NDA-less The Good, The Bad, and The Ugly
- Aerial Cyber Apocalypse: If we can do it... they can too.
- A Crushing Blow At the Heart of SAP J2EE Engine
- Crypto for Pentesters
- Hacking Medical Devices for Fun and Insulin: Breaking the Human SCADA System
- Attacking Clientside JIT Compilers
- Analyzing SPDY: Getting to know the new web protocol
- Playing In The Reader X Sandbox
- Inside Apple's MDM Black Box
- Reverse Engineering Browser Components: Dissecting and Hacking Silverlight, HTML 5 and Flex
- PANEL: Owning Your Phone at Every Layer
- Sour Pickles
- Macs in the Age of the APT
- Server-Side JavaScript Injection: Attacking NoSQL and Node.js
- Corporate Espionage for Dummies: The Hidden Threat of Embedded Web Servers
- Staring into the Abyss: The Dark Side of Security and Professional Intelligence
- Weapons of Targeted Attack: Modern Document Exploit Techniques
- Constant Insecurity: Things you didn't know about (PE) Portable Executable file format
- Sticking to the Facts: Scientific Study of Static Analysis Tools
- The Rustock Botnet Takedown
- Vulnerability Extrapolation or 'Give me more Bugs like that, please?'
- WORKSHOP - Investigating Live CDs using Volatility and Physical Memory Analysis
- WORKSHOP - Easy and quick vulnerability hunting in Windows
- WORKSHOP - Binary Instrumentation Workshop for Security Experts
- WORKSHOP - Infosec 2021: A Career Odyssey
- WORKSHOP - Advanced Wi-Fi Security Penetration Testing
- WORKSHOP - Breaking Encryption in the Cloud: Cheap, GPU Assisted Supercomputing for Everyone
- WORKSHOP - Zero Day Malware Cleaning with the Sysinternals Tools
- WORKSHOP - Pentesting the Smart Grid
- WORKSHOP - The Art of Exploiting Lesser Known Injection Flaws
- Affiliate Programs: Legitimate Business or Fuelling Cybercrime?
- Overcoming iOS Data Protection to Re-enable iPhone Forensic
- PPI-Geolocation: The Next Generation of 802.11 Visualization and Geo-Location
- Familiarity Breeds Contempt: The Honeymoon Effect and the Role of Legacy Code in Zero-Day Vulnerabilities
- The Troika of E-Discovery: Ethics, ESI, and Expertise in a Web 2.0 World
- Killing the Myth of Cisco IOS Diversity: Towards Reliable, Large-Scale Exploitation of Cisco IOS
- IEEE Software Taggant System
- OAuth – Securing the Insecure
- Heap Spray Detection with Heap Inspector
- Function Rerouting from Kernel Land "Hades"
- The Ultimate Study of Real-Life SSL Issues
- SSH as the next back door. Are you giving hackers root access?

(highlight briefings in bold as we provide links to questions)

Comment: @Zuly-Gonzalez What briefings were you planning on attending or tweeting about?

Comment: Oh man, I'm just seeing this thread now. That sucks! This is a great list @this.josh. I wish I had seen it before. Although this list is still useful. Defcon is going on now and they tend to redo some of the same talks. Here's [the schedule](http://www.defcon.org/html/defcon-19/dc-19-schedule.html) for those interested. I'll start tweeting these.

Answer (score 2):

Briefing: Apple iOS Security Evaluation: Vulnerability Analysis and Data Encryption

[iOS/Android authentication and security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5082/ios-android-authentication-and-security)

[iOS Encryption Details](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1107/ios-encryption-details)

[How effective is iPhone 3GS and 4 device-at-rest encryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/581/how-effective-is-iphone-3gs-and-4-encryption)

[Best practices for securing an iPhone](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5324/best-practices-for-securing-an-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

For the Briefing: Hacking Androids for Profit we could link through to

[Best practices for securing an Android device](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4391/485)

[Android API development security pitfalls](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/5107/485)

Answer (score 2):

Briefing: Post Memory Corruption Memory Analysis

[How does System Memory Dump work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5194/how-does-system-memory-dump-work)

please add or modify as you see fit...

Answer (score 2):

Briefing: Mobile Malware Madness, and How To Cap the Mad Hatters

[Can a mobile phone battery contain malware?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/can-a-mobile-phone-battery-contain-malware)

[Vulnerabilities common only in mobile solutions?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/290/vulnerabilities-common-only-in-mobile-solutions)

please add or modify as you see fit...

Answer (score 2):

Briefing: USB: Undermining Security Barriers

[Is disabling auto-run enough to protect against malicious code from removable media automatically infecting a machine?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2592/is-disabling-auto-run-enough-to-protect-against-malicious-code-from-removable-med)

please add or modify as you see fit...

Answer (score 2):

Briefing: Black Ops of TCP/IP 2011

[Are some uncommon TCP ports scanned less than others?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5799/are-some-uncommon-tcp-ports-scanned-less-than-others)

[IP Conflicts / Spoofing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3406/ip-conflicts-spoofing)

[How can a company reduce exposure to packet spoofing? What solution should exist, but doesn't?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1044/how-can-a-company-reduce-exposure-to-packet-spoofing-what-solution-should-exist)

[What are the risks associated with relying on IPSec IP Filtering?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3909/what-are-the-risks-associated-with-relying-on-ipsec-ip-filtering)

[Solaris: IP Spoofing Across Ethernet Ports](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5643/solaris-ip-spoofing-across-ethernet-ports)

[Can ipopts be used to circumvent a pf or iptables firewall source IP based blocking?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4772/can-ipopts-be-used-to-circumvent-a-pf-or-iptables-firewall-source-ip-based-blocki)

[How do I identify an unknown port/protocol that my IDS picks up?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/how-do-i-identify-an-unknown-port-protocol-that-my-ids-picks-up)

[Are there valid reasons for spoofing an address?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1063/are-there-valid-reasons-for-spoofing-an-address)

[Reject IP packets with an ICMP error, or just drop them?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3290/reject-ip-packets-with-an-icmp-error-or-just-drop-them)

[What security risks does IP spoofing bring?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/what-security-risks-does-ip-spoofing-bring)

[Port Knocking is it a good idea?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/port-knocking-is-it-a-good-idea)

[Security risk of PING?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/security-risk-of-ping)

Answer (score 2):

Briefing: The Ultimate Study of Real-Life SSL Issues

[How to detect "forged" SSL certificates from the webserver end](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5815/how-to-detect-forged-ssl-certificates-from-the-webserver-end)

[How can I determine the encryption strength of an SSL connection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5607/how-can-i-determine-the-encryption-strength-of-an-ssl-connection)

[SSL TLS renegotiation vulnerability - current situation in clients](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/ssl-tls-renegotiation-vulnerability-current-situation-in-clients)

[SSL Session resumption and IDs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5511/ssl-session-resumption-and-ids)

[How secure is SSL?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5167/how-secure-is-ssl)

[What's the difference between SSL, TLS, and HTTPS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/whats-the-difference-between-ssl-tls-and-https)

[Paypal IPN, SSL and man-in-the-middle attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5063/paypal-ipn-ssl-and-man-in-the-middle-attacks)

[Secure communication between applications using SSL Certificates](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4605/secure-communication-between-applications-using-ssl-certificates)